# Need assistance reviewing program

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to create a program where you select one of the four numbers, each giving a different result besides 2 of them. Selecting 10 will square it, making the answer 100. Selecting 9 will ask you to select a different number, selecting 2 or 3 will multiply the number by 99.

The issue I am having is that one out of the four numbers work, if entered 9 it will prompt the user to select a different number, which is correct. However, selecting 10, 3 or 2 will give the answer 0, which is not correct. Although directly typing in 10, 3 or 2 will not provide the right answer, if you type in 9 first, then select 2 or 3, it'll output the correct answer, typing 10 will give you 990.

Here is what I have. Where did I go wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
int num1, answer;
num1=answer=0;

   printf ("Choose a number 2, 3, 9, 10: "); 
   scanf ("%d", &num1); 

while (num1 == 9) 
 {
   if (num1 == 10)
  {    answer = num1^2;
  }
     if (num1 == 9)
   {     printf ("Please choose another number: ");
       scanf ("%d", &num1); 
   }
       if (num1 == 2||3)
         answer = num1 * 99; 
 }
 printf ("Your answer is: %d", answer);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your braces/indentation style is rather weird...

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I'll fix it. I have it differently on Dev-c++ complier.

Comment: Dev-C++ is horribly outdated. It's pretty much the worst IDE you can use nowadays. It also ships with a just as outdated compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int num1, answer;
    num1=answer=0;

    printf("Choose a number 2, 3, 9, 10: "); 
    scanf("%d", &num1); 

    while (num1 == 9){
        printf ("Please choose another number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &num1);
    }
    if (num1 == 10){
        answer = num1 * num1;
    } else if (num1 == 2 || num1 == 3){
        answer = num1 * 99; 
    } else {
        ;//choice other number!!
    }
    printf ("Your answer is: %d\n", answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you explain to me your corrections please. Thank you!

Comment: @Jetser chrk has already been described, i add that part of  `while (num1 == 9){ ... }` this does not enter the loop if `num1` isn't 9.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `num1^2` won't calculate the square of `num1`, but will [bitwise `XOR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) its value with `2`.

---

In addition to that,

```
if (num1 == 2||3)
```

is same as:

```
if ((num == 2) || (3))
```

which is always true.

Comment: Thanks for your response chrk. num1^2 works with dev-c++, I have successfully done it previously. Also yes it is the same, but however it does not seem to work in this program when selecting 2 or 3. It still gives off answer as 0.